# i want to get http response of a webpage after the ajax response is loaded

Tags: c#, .net, httpwebrequest, web-crawler

usually when v get the response. the html is without the ajax response. coz it is requested latter.
but i want the source of the page containing the ajax request's response.

Answer (score 0):

You can use fiddler to get the content of all requests/responses: http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/

Comment: That lets you do exactly what you want; It shows you what is being sent over the wire for regular and AJAX requests/responses both.

Answer (score 0):

You need to mention what type of ajax operations you are using. If its not update panel related / don't include ViewState and anything that makes it hard to handle in the page, then you can just **make a separate request for the ajax resource just like the page does. Use fiddler to see what is sent in those ajax requests**.

**If the above don't fit the bill, then use WatiN or Selenium instead** of HttpWebRequest to hit the page. That is slower than the simple direct requests, but it'll actually execute the page in the context of a browser and let you do pretty much anything the user does (well, highly limited if things like silverlight,flash, etc are involved).